# Mediawiki thumbnail directory is almost as big as the image directory itself

Tags: mediawiki

Mediawiki installed with Softaculous (very recently upgraded to 1.35.0)

I was running out of space on my webhosting earlier so I ran

```
$ php deleteArchivedFiles.php --delete --force
$ php cleanupUploadStash.php
```

which saved me quite some storage but today I noticed that the `images/thumb/` directory is 922MB while the folders actually holding the images (`images/[...]/`) are all together 1.2GB.
Also the biggest file in the thumb folder is 4MB. Why are these thumbnails so big?

Can I just delete all the contents of this folder as suggested on [this old post](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Ta64wbe7eir59qas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`$wgGenerateThumbnailOnParse`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgGenerateThumbnailOnParse) is false, there is no harm in deleting thumbnails; they will be regenerated when needed. If it is true, thumbnails will only be generated when the page is parsed; you'll end up with broken image links if you delete them. (You can e.g. set [`$wgCacheEpoch`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheEpoch) or use `action=purge` to re-parse pages, or just wait long enough for the parser cache to expire.) It probably won't help much in any case, those thumbnails will be regenerated eventually.

There are a lot more thumbnails than originals (every different size is a separate thumbnail) so taking up a lot of space is normal. A 4MB thumbnail is strange but maybe it is a large image that is displayed in almost-full-size on some page?

Comment: I deleted all files and folder in the thumb directory and thought that was that. But now I discovered that the thumbnails are not being generated `Error creating thumbnail: Unable to save thumbnail to destination`. Should I have kept the folder structure in the thumb folder? And only deleted the image files inside of the folders?

Comment: Hmm I recreated the folder structure and that didn't solve it. So it's probably something else. Maybe the update to 1.35.0. Anyway it doesn't belong in this question I think.

Comment: Permission problems, presumably? The directories don't need to exist (maybe the `thumb` directory itself does, I'm not sure about that).

Comment: Somehow the update (done by softaculous) added:
`$wgTmpDirectory = "/home/username/tmp_9cd4z8";` 
to the local settings. And although that folder was there and writable, thumbnailing did not work until I removed that line of config. Strange.